# Get Item from WPF DataGridRow

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a mouse leave event for when the mouse leaves a row

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
     <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
           <EventSetter Event="MouseLeave" Handler="Row_MouseLeave"></EventSetter>
     </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

So in the handler, I try to get the underlining item that in bounded to the row

```
private void Row_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs args)
{
   DataGridRow dgr = sender as DataGridRow;

   <T> = dgr.Item as <T>;
}
```

However, the item is a placeholder object and not the item itself.

Normally you can do what I want via the DataGrid selectedIndex property.

```
 DataGridRow dgr = (DataGridRow)(dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(dg.SelectedIndex));

 <T> = dgr.Item as <T>
```

But as the `ItemSource` is bounded to the DataGrid, and not the DataGridRow, the DataGridRow cannot see the collection that was bounded to the grid...(I assume)

But as I am not selecting a row, I cant really do this. So is there a way I can do what I want?

Cheers

Comment: The .Item object is {NewItemPlaceholder}

Comment: How would it ever be the actual Item that you want..? It seems to me that If you do a MouseLeave on a new row, it will always return the PlaceHolder then..

Comment: It isnt a new row.. the row has an item already bounded to it. I would expect what your saying if it was a new row generated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you attach an event handler to the `DataGridRow.MouseLeave` event, then the `sender` input parameter will be the `DataGridRow` as you correctly showed us. However, after that you are mistaken. The `DataGridRow.Item` property *will* return the data item from inside the `DataGridRow` *unless you mouse over the last (empty or new) row in the `DataGrid`*... in that case and that case alone, the `DataGridRow.Item` property will return a `{NewItemPlaceholder}` of type `MS.Internal.NamedObject`:

```
private void Row_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs args)
{
    DataGridRow dataGridRow = sender as DataGridRow;
    if (dataGridRow.Item is YourClass)
    {
        YourClass yourItem = dataGridRow.Item as YourClass;
    }
    else if (dataGridRow.Item is MS.Internal.NamedObject)
    {
        // Item is new placeholder
    }
}
```

Try mousing over a row that actually contains data and then you should find that data object in the `DataGridRow.Item` property.